# How to open Outlook template with using Python

Tags: python, windows, email, templates, outlook

I would like to know if there is a way to open a template outloook which is stored on my Network Attached Storage (NAS). I'm trying to open test.msg

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"C:\Users\Cyche\test.msg")
```

I tried msg.open() it doesnt work :/

Comment: Open programmatically using Outlook Object Model?

Comment: there is a way to open email without sending it ?

Comment: Yes. Once again, what exactly are you trying to do? Open a template programmatically modify it, save it? Using which API? Where is the code running? Is Outlook installed? You need to be a lot more specific than that.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is: are you unsure how to modify a property (`msg.Subject = "Test"`)? Save it (`msg.Save`)?

Comment: sorry i'm not confortable in english, i use translator. I added the start of my code. I want to open the template test.msg with outlook

Comment: See [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/).

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what you are asking, but the following should do the job.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"C:\Users\Cyche\test.msg")
msg.Subject = "Modified Subject"
msg.Save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dmitry, you helped me.

I just add this line to open the template :

msg.Display()

Ty a lot

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).